# how to find top level parent for each child record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have two columns of data in a table `trans`:

```
transid      ptransid
---------------------
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            1
5            3
6            2
7            2
8            7
9            8
10           4
```

I would like to show the result like

```
transid      ptransid
----------------------
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            1
5            3
6            2
7            2
8            2
9            2
10           1
```

Query:

```
select 
    T0.transid, T3.ptransid
from 
    trans T0
left join 
    trans T1 on T0.ptransid = T1.transid
left join 
    trans T2 on T1.ptransid = T2.transid
left join 
    trans T3 on T2.ptransid = T3.transid
```

But the above sample is too simple. The layer may have 30, as the above sample is only 4.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Also, please explain your question in more detail. What do you mean by "show the reason"? What do you mean by "earliest number between two columns"?

Comment: Are you saying you _might_ have the need to do 30 self joins, or you will _always_ have the need for 30 self joins?

Comment: I am the first time to post. Gordon Linoff - I am using SQL server 2008. Amadan - I just want to show the result like the bottom one. Tim Biegeleisen - Yes, I might have 30 self joins or more, it depends on the data transaction.

Comment: Have any method that is not necessary to have the self join?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/233a9/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(transid INT, ptransid INT)
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES
(1    ,        1),
(2    ,        2),
(3    ,        3),
(4    ,        1),
(5    ,        3),
(6    ,        2),
(7    ,        2),
(8    ,        7),
(9    ,        8),
(10   ,        4)
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH c AS (
         SELECT transid, 
                ptransid, 
                ptransid AS topptransid 
         FROM   test_table 
         WHERE  transid = ptransid 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT T.transid, 
                T.ptransid, 
                c.topptransid 
         FROM   test_table AS T 
                INNER JOIN c 
                        ON T.ptransid = c.transid 
         WHERE  T.transid <> T.ptransid) 
SELECT transid, 
       topptransid 
FROM   c 
ORDER  BY transid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/233a9/1/0)**:

```
| transid | topptransid |
|---------|-------------|
|       1 |           1 |
|       2 |           2 |
|       3 |           3 |
|       4 |           1 |
|       5 |           3 |
|       6 |           2 |
|       7 |           2 |
|       8 |           2 |
|       9 |           2 |
|      10 |           1 |
```

Comment: M. Ali, thanks for your help. I would like to check with my data with your query. And I will apply it on php.

Comment: Yes basically this query will get you all the top level parents for all the transIds , you didn't explain your requirement very well I just guessed it by comparing your sample data and desired output.

Comment: Thanks, M. Ali, you are smart. I simple check my result, it is correct. Thank you very much.